# Randomizing specific position of numbers

Tags: excel, vba, basic

For example, I have numbers 1,9,7,4 and I want to randomize their position so I will get 9,1,4,7 or 7,1,9,4 etc. Do you know how? Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. The best method would depend on what you plan to do with the result.

Comment: This also depends on which dialect of basic you are using.

Comment: Three different people, probably all professionals, answered your homework for you. The least you could do is mark one of the three correct answers as the accepted answer.  You could also thank them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic vba randomize into a dictionary object.

```
Dim vals As Variant, ord As Object

Set ord = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

vals = Array(1, 4, 7, 9)

Do While ord.Count < (UBound(vals) + 1)
    ord.Item(vals(Application.RandBetween(LBound(vals), UBound(vals)))) = vbNullString
Loop

Debug.Print Join(ord.keys, ", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more likely (simplistic) example: (I hope I didn't do your homework for you)

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim i1&, i2&, iswap&, a4 As Variant
  a4 = Array(1, 9, 7, 4)
  For i1 = 0 To 3
    i2 = Int(Rnd() * 4) ' random integer 0 to 3
    iswap = a4(i1) ' swap(a4(i1), a4(i2))
    a4(i1) = a4(i2)
    a4(i2) = iswap
  Next i1
  Debug.Print a4(0); a4(1); a4(2); a4(3) ' Ctl-G to view, F7 to get back to code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the basic dialect so here is some code:

```
a(1) = 1 : a(2) = 4 : a(3) = 7 : a(4) = 9
FOR l = 1 TO 4
    SWAP a(l), a(INT(RND * 4 + 1))
NEXT
END
```